# My 1991 Honda Accord grinds on third gear!

Tags: honda, accord, manual-transmission, gears

My 1991 Honda Accord grinds on third gear what could this mean and how can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It probably means that the synchro which meshes the third gear is bad or going bad. The only fix for this is a rebuild or finding a used replacement for a cheaper alternative.

Comment: I agree, leaning hard towards the used replacement. After 23 years, I'd be surprised if it WASN'T grinding a little on at least one gear. Synchromesh is GOOD, but it's not wearproof.